# Como relacionar dois registros de forma elegante?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Em determinado ponto de minha aplicação estou criando um post e relacionando este com o usuário da sessão:

```
public function adicionar(CadEditPost $request)
{        
    $request->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);

    if(Post::create($request->all()))
    {
        return redirect('/painel/posts')
                ->with(['status' => 'success', 'mensagem' => 'Post adicionado com sucesso!']);
    }

    return redirect('/painel/posts')
            ->with(['status' => 'error', 'mensagem' => 'Ocorreu um erro ao tentar adicionar o post!']);
}
```

Existe uma forma mais "elegante" ou adequada de gerar este relacionamento ao invés de usar:

```
$request->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
```

Obs: Na tabela post **user_id** é uma *foreign* que aponta para a tabela **users** coluna **id**.

Será que está forma seria melhor:

```
Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());
```

Model User:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use App\Notifications\NotificarTrocaSenha;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Código dos status existentes
     */
    const STATUS = [
        0 => 'Inativo',
        1 => 'Ativo',
        2 => 'Bloqueado',
        3 => 'Excluido'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'sexo'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Retorna os posts relacionados ao usuário
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany 
     */
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Post');
    }

    /**
     * Send the password reset notification.
     *
     * @param  string  $token
     * @return void
     */
    public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new NotificarTrocaSenha($token));
    }

    /**
     * Traduz a sigla sexo para Feminino ou Masculino
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSexoMutatorAttribute()
    {
        return ($this->sexo == 'f') ? 'Feminino' : 'Masculino';
    }

    /**
     * Traduz a sigla status para algo compreensivo
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatusMutatorAttribute()
    {
        $status = self::STATUS;
        return $status[$this->status];
    }
}
```

Model Post:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    /**
     * Código dos status existentes
     */
    const STATUS = [
        0 => 'Rascunho',
        1 => 'Publicado',
        2 => 'Excluído'
    ];

    /**
     * Lista de campos que podem ser submetidos em massa (form)
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'titulo', 'conteudo', 'status', 'capa'
    ];

    /**
     * Retorna o relacionamento de post com a tabela user
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    /**
     * Traduz a sigla status para algo compreensivo
     * 
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStatusMutatorAttribute()
    {
        $status = self::STATUS;
        return $status[$this->status];
    }
}
```

Comment: Existe sim, mas depende da direção da relation. Pode postar o métodos posts do seu User ?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei as model user e post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Formas são diversas:

```
Auth::user()->posts()->create($request->all());
```

---

*ou*

```
$user = Auth::user()
if ($user)
{
    $user->posts()->create($request->all());
}
```

---

*ou*

na classe [`FormRequest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) no método `authorize()`

```
class CadEditPost extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
         $this->merge(['user_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
         return true;
    }
}
```

---

*ou*

Pode criar um [`Observer`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers) com o método `saving`:

```
class PostObserver {

    public function saving($model)
    {
        $model->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    }

}
```

na classe `Post`

```
class Post extends Model
{

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot(); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
        parent::observe(new PostObserver());
    }
```

Todas as vezes que for salvar (`save()`) é passado o ***id*** do usuário autenticado.

<sub>**Particularmente, a primeira que é a forma mais elegante para esse determinado código, então, tudo vai depender do seu código e contexto. Em determinado sistemas aonde é feito uma auditoria de registros quem gravou um determinado registro a última forma seria a ideal.**</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No seu Post você pode utilizar também o `associate`. Ele Irá inserir o ID do usuário no seu Post. Veja na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

```
public function adicionar(CadEditPost $request)
{        
    $post = new Post($request->all());

    $post->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    if($post->save()) {
        // Sucesso
    }
}
```